# Why am I getting "incompatible pointer type"?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, foundation

I am trying to create a custom object that simply inherits the NSString class and overrides the 'description' method.

When I compile, however, I am getting a warning:

> Incompatible pointer types initializing 'OverrideTester *' with an expression of type 'NSString *'

Here is my code:

**main.m**

```
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>
#import <Foundation/NSString.h>
#import <Foundation/NSAutoreleasePool.h>
#import "OverrideTester.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *str = @"Programming is fun";
    OverrideTester *strOverride = @"Overriding is fun";

    NSLog (@"%@", str);
    NSLog (@"%@", strOverride);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

**OverrideTester.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface OverrideTester : NSString
-(void) description;
@end
```

**OverrideTester.m**

```
#import "OverrideTester.h"

@implementation OverrideTester

-(void) description

{
    NSLog(@"DESCRIPTION!\n");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSString` is part of a class cluster. You cannot just create arbitrary subclasses of it, and when you do, you can't assign constant strings to them (which are type `NXConstantString`). See [Subclassing Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) in the NSString documentation. Generally you don't want to subclass `NSString`. There are better solutions for most problems.

Comment: You certainly *can* create arbitrary subclasses of `NSString` or any other class cluster.  You simply have to override the methods in the core of the class.  However, subclassing a class cluster is typically very rare and most certainly **not** something that should be done simply as a learning exercise!

Comment: I misused the word "arbitrary" here. I meant "just by tossing `:NSString` onto your definition."

Answer (score 2):

1. you are assigning an instance of `NSString` to your variable of type `OverrideTester`.  If you want an instance of your class, you need to instantiate an instance of that class;  type-casting will *never* change the class of an instance.
2. `description` is defined as returning an `NSString*`:

   `- (NSString *)description;`
3. Do **not** try to learn about subclassing and overriding methods by subclassing `NSString` (or any other class cluster).   If you want to play with subclassing and such -- a very good idea when new to the language, assuredly -- then subclass NSObject, potentially multiple levels , and play there.

---

> How do you mean to subclass NSObject,
>   potentially multiple levels? Isn't it
>   possible NSObject might have
>   conflicting methods compared to other
>   class clusters or just not have them
>   available to override?

If your goal is to figure out how method overrides work (which I thought it was), then you'd be better off doing it entirely yourself.

I may have mis-read your question.

In any case, subclassing NSString is pretty much never done.  There are very very few cases where it is useful.   Overriding `description` in anything but custom classes specifically for debugging purposes is useful, yes.   Calling `description` in production code should never be done.

> Also, why would description return an
>   NSString* in this code?

What would happen if something that expects an `NSString*` return value were to call your version that doesn't return anything?

A crash.

Comment: How do you mean to subclass NSObject, potentially multiple levels? Isn't it possible NSObject might have conflicting methods compared to other class clusters or just not have them available to override?

Comment: Also, why would description return an NSString* in this code?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a variable named `strOverride` of type pointer to `OverrideTester`. But to that variable, you are trying to assign a pointer to an `NSString`. You cannot assign a superclass to a variable of a subclass. Imagine a generic class `TwoWheeled` and a derived class `Motorbike`. A `Motorbike` can be treated like a `TwoWheeled`, but not the other way round as the `Motorbike` has features a normal `TwoWheeled` might not have like a motor.